# C "expected expression before 'struct'" error since using typedef or header

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm fairly new to C programming (did a little bit of lazarus and java before, but nothing mayor) and I tried to program a little text-rpg to learn the basics.
Now I'm getting a strange error while compiling since I tried to make part of the program a header. At the same time I stopped writing struct everywhere and used typedef, so the error might also originate from there.
Here's my code:

**advancedgame.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "advancedgameglobals.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
initiateglobals();
destroygameglobals();
return 0;
}
```

**advancedgameglobals.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "advancedgameglobals.h"

PLAYER *player_create(char *name, int con, int str, int agi, int wis){
  PLAYER *who = malloc(sizeof(PLAYER));
  assert(who != NULL);

  who->name = strdup(name);
  who->con = con;
  who->str = str;
  who->agi = agi;
  who->wis = wis;
  int def = con / 5;
  int maxhp = con * 10;
  int hp = maxhp;
  int maxmp = wis * 5;
  int mp = maxmp;
  who->def = def;
  who->maxhp = maxhp;
  who->hp = hp;
  who->maxmp = maxmp;
  who->mp = mp;
  who->exp = 0;
  who->level = 1;
}

char * determine_item_type(int type){
  char *typename;
  if(type == 1){
    typename = "longsword";}
  else if(type == 2){
    typename = "wooden shield";}
  else{
    typename = "empty slot";}
  return typename;
}

INVENTORY *inventory_create(char *name){
  INVENTORY *who = malloc(sizeof(INVENTORY));
  assert(who != NULL);

  who->name = strdup(name);
  int slot0 = 0;
  int slot1 = 0;
  int slot2 = 0;
  int slot3 = 0;
  int slot4 = 0;
  int slot5 = 0;
  int slot6 = 0;
  int slot7 = 0;
  int slot8 = 0;
  int slot9 = 0;

  who->slot0 = slot0;
  who->slot0name = determine_item_type(slot0);
  who->slot1 = slot1;
  who->slot1name = determine_item_type(slot1);
  who->slot2 = slot2;
  who->slot2name = determine_item_type(slot2);
  who->slot3 = slot3;
  who->slot3name = determine_item_type(slot3);
  who->slot4 = slot4;
  who->slot4name = determine_item_type(slot4);
  who->slot5 = slot5;
  who->slot5name = determine_item_type(slot5);
  who->slot6 = slot6;
  who->slot6name = determine_item_type(slot6);
  who->slot7 = slot7;
  who->slot7name = determine_item_type(slot7);
  who->slot8 = slot8;
  who->slot8name = determine_item_type(slot8);
  who->slot9 = slot9;
  char *test = determine_item_type(slot9);
  who->slot9name = test;//determine_item_type(slot9);
}

char * determine_town_type(int type){
  char *typename;
  if(type == 1){
    typename = "shop";}
  else if(type == 2){
    typename = "Colloseum";}
  else{
    typename = "empty shack";}
  return typename;
}

TOWN *town_create(char *name, int slot0, int slot1, int slot2, int slot3){
  TOWN *who = malloc(sizeof(TOWN));
  assert(who != NULL);
  who->name = strdup(name);
  who->slot0 = slot0;
  who->slot0name = determine_town_type(slot0);
  who->slot1 = slot1;
  who->slot1name = determine_town_type(slot1);
  who->slot2 = slot2;
  who->slot2name = determine_town_type(slot2);
  who->slot3 = slot3;
  char *test = determine_town_type(slot3);
  who->slot3name = test;//determine_town_type(slot3);
}

ENEMY *enemy_create(char *name, int con, int str, int agi, int wis){
  ENEMY *who = malloc(sizeof(ENEMY));
  assert(who != NULL);

  who->name = strdup(name);
  who->con = con;
  who->str = str;
  who->agi = agi;
  who->wis = wis;
  int def = con / 5;
  int maxhp = con * 10;
  int hp = maxhp;
  int maxmp = wis * 5;
  int mp = maxmp;
  who->def = def;
  who->maxhp = maxhp;
  who->hp = hp;
  who->maxmp = maxmp;
  who->mp = mp;
  int exp = con+str+agi+wis;
  who->exp = exp;
  who->level = exp / 50;
}

void player_destroy(PLAYER *who){
  assert(who != NULL);

  free(who->name);
  free(who);
}

void enemy_destroy(ENEMY *who){
  assert(who != NULL);

  free(who->name);
  free(who);
}

void inventory_destroy(INVENTORY *who){
  assert(who != NULL);

  free(who->name);
  free(who);
}

void town_destroy(TOWN *who){
  assert(who != NULL);

  free(who->name);
  free(who);
}

int initiateglobals(void)
{
  PLAYER *PLAYER = player_create(
                    "Player", 10, 10, 10, 10);
  INVENTORY *INVENTORY = inventory_create(
                         "Inventory");
  TOWN *TOWN = town_create(
                  "Antaria", 2, 1, 0, 0);
  return 0;
}

int destroygameglobals(void)
{
  player_destroy(PLAYER);
  inventory_destroy(INVENTORY);
  town_destroy(TOWN);
}
```

**advancedgameglobals.h:**

```
#ifndef ADVANCEDGAMEGLOBALS_H
#define ADVANCEDGAMEGLOBALS_H

typedef struct player{
  char *name;
  int con;
  int def;
  int str;
  int agi;
  int wis;
  int maxhp;
  int hp;
  int maxmp;
  int mp;
  int exp;
  int level;
} PLAYER;

typedef struct enemy{
  char *name;
  int con;
  int def;
  int str;
  int agi;
  int wis;
  int maxhp;
  int hp;
  int maxmp;
  int mp;
  int exp;
  int level;
} ENEMY;

typedef struct inventory{
  char *name;
  int slot0;
  char *slot0name;
  int slot1;
  char *slot1name;
  int slot2;
  char *slot2name;
  int slot3;
  char *slot3name;
  int slot4;
  char *slot4name;
  int slot5;
  char *slot5name;
  int slot6;
  char *slot6name;
  int slot7;
  char *slot7name;
  int slot8;
  char *slot8name;
  int slot9;
  char *slot9name;
} INVENTORY;

typedef struct town{
  char *name;
  int slot0;
  char *slot0name;
  int slot1;
  char *slot1name;
  int slot2;
  char *slot2name;
  int slot3;
  char *slot3name;
} TOWN;

PLAYER *player_create(char *name, int con, int str, int agi, int wis);
char * determine_item_type(int type);
INVENTORY *inventory_create(char *name);
char * determine_town_type(int type);
TOWN *town_create(char *name, int slot0, int slot1, int slot2, int slot3);
ENEMY *enemy_create(char *name, int con, int str, int agi, int wis);
void player_destroy(PLAYER *who);
void enemy_destroy(ENEMY *who);
void inventory_destroy(INVENTORY *who);
void town_destroy(TOWN *who);
int initiateglobals(void);
int destroyglobals(void);

#endif
```

Now the error I'm getting tells me the following:

```
error: expected expression before 'PLAYER'
player_destroy(PLAYER);
error: expected expression before 'INVENTORY'
inventory_destroy(INVENTORY);
error: expected expression before 'TOWN'
town_destroy(TOWN);
```

I'm getting this error whenever I try to make a function using any of my structures. Most likely this is a very dumb error and I'm sorry about that, but I would appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: This may not be the cause of that error message, but I don't think you want those `extern`s in your `advancedgameglobals.c` file (and probably not in the declaration either).\

Comment: Only use all-uppercase names for macros and _enum-constants_. That is the only widely accepted naming convention in C.

Comment: @crashmstr I've removed them now, just had them there because I saw them in a tutorial I found when transitioning to a header file. Thanks.

Comment: @Olaf Also something I found in an allegedly reliable "tutorial", I will change that, thanks.

Comment: There was a right answer and was deleted. The problem are lines like `PLAYER *PLAYER = player_create("Player", 10, 10, 10, 10);`. In C when you define a typedef it behaves like a new keyword. You can not use a variable of the same name. In C++ you can.

Comment: @Marian I'm sorry, but could you elaborate? I have to admit that pointers and such still confuse me a little, so I don't exactly know what to change in my code. If you would give me an example using the "player" part, I could change town and inventory on my own and understand a little more about the proper syntax.

Comment: @Marian: actually you can very well use the same name in different scopes. But you should not (and that applies to C++, too). OP should enable "shadowing" warnings.

Comment: Note: You should use `const char*` instead of `char*` to store pointers to (the first elements of) string literals because modifying them is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

- The function `initiateglobals()` initializes local variables, not global variables. Naming variables to the same name as types is also not good because it is confusing.
- The function calls in `destroygameglobals()` is not good. You have to use names of variables instead of type names to pass as arguments.

To fix:

- Declare global variables to be initialized in `initiateglobals()` and have the function initialize the global variables, not local variables. The names of variables should be differ from the type names to avoid confusion.
- Use names of the declared global variables, not type names as arguments in function calls in `destroygameglobals()`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I don't completely understand how to execute what you just told me. Global variables are initialized with the "extern" tag, right? But I can't do that with a typedef (multiple storage classes), and I also can't write "extern PLAYER *PLAYER". I'm sure this sounds very badly informed and that I should study the basics more before attempting to do this. But I think that once I've seen the solution to this I will be able to understand the rest more easily.

Comment: @Plebejer I don't see any "extern" tag in your code posted here, but initializing variables with "extern" tag is unusual though it is allowed. `extern` is for *declaring* what will be *defined elsewhere*. Also, why are you willing to use variable names that are the same as type names?

Comment: in the beginning, everything in advancedgameglobals was tagged extern (except the structs obviously)... removed that after a comment by crashmstr telling me I don't need them. And the variable names... well, let's just say that wasn't the most thought out plan.

Comment: I DID IT! ^^ Thank you for your help. I had a wrong conception about "extern", but now I got it. Renamed most variables (player_struct for example) and typed `player_struct* player_root` (for example) behind those typedef declarations in advancedgameglobals.h and worked with those variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with this function.

```
int destroygameglobals(void)
{
  player_destroy(PLAYER);
  inventory_destroy(INVENTORY);
  town_destroy(TOWN);
}
```

Check function calls in this function. Instead of passing some variable as arguments, you are passing data type as arguments. Which is no acceptable.